# Reading in non-consecutive columns using XLSX.gettable?

Tags: dataframe, file-io, julia, xlsx

Is there a way to read in a selection of non-consecutive columns of Excel data using XLSX.gettable? I’ve read the documentation here [XLSX.jl Tutorial](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/), but it’s not clear whether it’s possible to do this. For example,

df = DataFrame(XLSX.gettable(sheet,"A:B")...)

selects the data in columns “A” and “B” of a worksheet called sheet. But what if I want columns A and C, for example? I tried

df = DataFrame(XLSX.gettable(sheet,["A","C"])...)

and similar variations of this, but it throws the following error: MethodError: no method matching gettable(::XLSX.Worksheet, ::Array{String,1}).

Is there a way to make this work with gettable, or is there a similar function which can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the current version of XLSX.jl:

If you look at the definition of `gettable` [here](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/master/src/table.jl#L514) you'll see that it calls

```
eachtablerow(sheet, cols;...)
```

which is defined [here](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/68a6cf5aff00987e82afb9684a71bb732a89928c/src/table.jl#L93) as accepting `Union{ColumnRange, AbstractString}` as input for the `cols` argument. The `cols` argument itself is converted to a `ColumnRange` object in the `eachtablerow` function, which is defined [here](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/68a6cf5aff00987e82afb9684a71bb732a89928c/src/types.jl#L95) as:

```
struct ColumnRange
    start::Int # column number
    stop::Int  # column number

    function ColumnRange(a::Int, b::Int)
        @assert a <= b "Invalid ColumnRange. Start column must be located before end column."
        return new(a, b)
    end
end
```

So it looks to me like only consecutive columns are working.

To get around this you should be able to just broadcast the `gettable` function over your column ranges and then concatenate the resulting DataFrames:

```
df = reduce(hcat, DataFrame.(XLSX.gettable.(sheet, ["A:B", "D:E"])))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately when I tried to run your code on my sample data, I got the error ```MethodError: no method matching length(::XLSX.Worksheet)```...

Comment: Ah sorry I hadn't actually tried this - that probably just means that `XLSX.Worksheet` is not broadcastable, try a comprehension `reduce(hcat, [DataFrame(XLSX.gettable(sheet, x)) for x in ["A:B", "D:E"]])`

Answer (score 0):

I found that to get @Nils Gudat's answer to work you need to add the  [`... operator`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...) to give

```
reduce(hcat, [DataFrame(XLSX.gettable(sheet, x)...) for x in ["A:B", "D:E"]])
```